# Why IDA 64 breaks the ASM view after patching a value

Tags: assembly, ida

I am new to IDA patching, or any binary patching whatsoever

I have an instruction that has a number, and I am changing that number. It works, but IDA view prints an error:

```
_ZNK4GNET13Skill6441Stub13PlayerFormulaEi endp ; sp-analysis failed
```

the instruction says:

```
mov eax, 3F800000h
```

the bytes are:

```
  B8 00 00 80 3F
```

and I change them to:

```
B8 6F 12 83 3A
```

which updates the ASM code to:

```
mov eax, 3A83126Fh
```

but I get the sp-analysis failed error and don't know why, I think I am patching the correct bytes with the correct values, I am changing a 1.0 to 0.001. and the file does work and takes the change I make, but Ida gets broken.

How can I solve this?